# Whenever installing React Native Gesture Handler it starts giving error

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am installing react navigation using the [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) but when I do install `npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`, it start giving me error in iOS.

Error is `Use of undeclared identifier 'UIScrollTypeMaskAll'` RNPanHandler.m

I follow all the steps of docs.

Xcode version:- 11.3.1

react native gesture handler version:- 1.9.0

I tried this too:-

1.

```
   import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; //by adding on top
   import * as React from 'react';
   import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

   export default function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>{/* Rest of your app code */}</NavigationContainer>
      );
     }
```

2. `rm -rf node_modules` and removing `package-lock.json` as well.
3. Installing React native gesture handler separately from [react native gesture handler](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation)
4. `pod install`

Comment: Did you run **pod install**?

Comment: yes I have run it also, sorry forgot to mention here

Comment: Which XCode version are you using? Also please mention your React Native Gesture Handler version.

Comment: xcode version- 11.3.1 RNGH version- 1.9.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is already mentioned here,

> https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1235

Try upgrading your XCode version to 12.2 or try degarding your React Native Gesture Handler version to 1.8.0

Answer (score 1):

The official doc says that you have to add this lib as the first import in the `index.js` file but your file looks like `App.js`.

Comment: I did try after importing in both file `index.js` and 'app.js`. Once at a time in index and app respectively as well as in both file at the same time

Comment: @ShanAlam Are you using expo?

Comment: Did you try to remove `Podfile.lock`? Maybe there is a cached error.

Comment: not yet, will check after removing `podfile.lock`

Comment: @ShanAlam Check [this](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1235#issuecomment-732769731). I think you should update your XCode.